# Mensagens de validação aparecendo antes de enviar formulário

Tags: ionic

Estou criando um formulário com Ionic e quero validar os campos depois do formulário submetido. Da maneira como estou fazendo, funciona, porém quando abro a página os campos já estão marcados como inválidos e eu quero que isso aconteça depois q o formulário seja submetido caso haja algum campo que não foi preenchido.

Como faço isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
<form name="Empresa" novalidate ng-submit="addEmpresa(Empresa);">
                      <div class="list">
                            <label class="item item-input" 
                                   ng-class="{'has-errors':Empresa.nomeemp.$invalid, 'no-errors':Empresa.nomeemp.$valid}">
                                <input type="text" 
                                       placeholder="Nome" 
                                       name="nomeemp" 
                                       ng-model="Empresa.nome" 
                                       ng-required="true">
                            </label>
                            <div class="error-container"
                                 ng-messages="Empresa.nomeemp.$error">
                                <div ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html"></div>
                            </div>

<button type="submit" class="button button-block button-energized">Cadastrar</button>

</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode validar também se o campo já foi modificado:

```
!Empresa.nomeemp.$pristine && Empresa.nomeemp.$invalid
```

`$pristine` quer dizer que o campo não foi modificado, neste caso está validando se o campo foi modificado e é invalido. 
Não sei como é sua function `addEmpresa`, mas se estiver recebendo o `form` você pode dar um `form.$setPristine();` que ele volta a ser um form "virgem" setando todos os campos como novos.